# OpenCV SVM - object does not belong to any of trained classes

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

I'm using OpenCV (3.1) SVM with 3 classes. Is there any way how to handle input data, which does not belong to any of these classes? Is there posibility to get probability from the prediciton?

I just simply want to mark data from unknown class as "Does not belong to any of trained classes".

Thank you

Comment: (1) Introduce 4th class or (2) train another binary classifier (e.g. SVM again) that classifies "known" vs "unknown" and pass "known" samples to 3-class SVN or (3) train one-vs-many SVM, or... Well there are many solutions. It is not really specific to OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [SVM docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html#cvsvm-predict)(the predict function, in particular), it seems that the best you can do is get the distance from the support vector, and it looks like you can only even get that from a binary classifier.

Not sure how constrained to OpenCV you are, but if you can use scikit learn for your problem, their SVM has a [predict_proba](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.predict_proba) function that should be helpful. There is also a predict_log_proba function, if that's your preference. Also, note that you'll need to set probability=true when calling the fit function if you go this route.

If you're contrained to C/C++, you might look into [LibSVM](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/), as they also have the ability to give the probabilities, although I'm not as familiar with their api. Also note that the OpenCV and scikit learn implementations are both based on LibSVM

Hope one of these works for you!